# IF function in Oracle to insert data into tables

Tags: sql, oracle, function, if-statement, plsql

I want to make function which inserts 'F' in a field, when field "NAME" ends by '%a' and 'M' if not. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Do you mean `update` a field?

Comment: No, there's a column named 'Sex' and if Name ends on 'a' i want it to insert F, otherwise insert M.

Comment: Check out case statements in oracle

Comment: Your query is `insert into tableA(sex_col, name_col) select  sex_col, name from ... ` ? then you could use `case statement`

Comment: `Insert` or `Update`? Do you need it a single time (pass through all data and `Update` the Sex column) or do you need that when a new `Insert` is made?

Comment: It's a new insert, i'm filling table with data, like this:
INSERT INTO table (name_col) values('value');
and i want to sex_col fill automatically with F or M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is called t, and the column names are col_name and col_sex, and the string you enter for col_name is string_value, then what you want is:

```
insert into t (col_came, col_sex) values (string_value, 
                                case when string_value like '%a' then 'F' else 'M' end);
```